# Why can't I call SetText on it which is

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, event-handling, settext

I wanted to display text in EditText when I clicked on this. But using it does not allow this.

`class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private val MY_LOG = "myLog"
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        .also {
            setContentView(it.root)
        }

    binding.etTest.setOnClickListener {
        binding.etTest.setText("$it")
        it.setText("String")

    }
}
```

}`

[image]

Why if "it" is EditText not working setText()?

Comment: _"Why if "it" is EditText"_  `it` isn't. `it` is a generic `View`.

Comment: binding.etTest.setOnClickListener {
            //binding.etTest.setText("$it")
            val check = it is EditText
            binding.etTest.setText("$check") //true
        }

Comment: The `is` operator performs a _runtime_  type check. The compiler sees a `View` instance, which doesn't have a `setText` function. You could write e.g. `(it as? EditText)?.setText("String")`

Comment: `(it as? EditText)?.setText("it as EditText")`
is working, very nice!

Answer (score 0):

Basically OnClickListener is interface which has onClick method which will give you View class and View class doesn't have any method for setText. Due to that you are not able to call setText method.

[image: OnClickListener implementation]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `it.setText("String")` doesn't work is because the it variable in the `binding.etTest.setOnClickListener` lambda refers to the View that was clicked, not specifically to the EditText itself. In this case the View that was clicked is the `RelativeLayout , ConstraintLayout , etc...` that contains the EditText.

So don't use `it`

You should use the actual view like in this case is the editText

You have to just call setText on the edittext

If you want to set the text when the edittext is clicked

```kotlin
    binding.etTest.setOnClickListener {
        binding.etTest.setText("Your text")
    }
```

and If you want to get the text from the edittext

```kotlin
    val text = binding.etTest.text
```

and voila

Comment: This is not correct. The `it` does *not* refer to the parent view as suggested here. It does refer to the clicked view, but as already mentioned `it` is of type `View` which doesn't have a `setText` method.